# Formula field on the Account Page

Tags: formula-field, account, roll-up-summary

I'm looking to create a formula field on the Accounts Page. I'm not sure how to go about setting this up. It needs to calculate the Account's lead conversion rate for that Account, which would take in the 'Number of Leads Converted' over the 'Total Number of Leads'. Is this possible? I've never created a formula field and looking for guidance with this issue.

As always thanks for your time and advice.

Comment: Do you already have the two fields you mentioned (Total Number of Leads, and Number of Converted Leads) working on the account?

Comment: Yeah that is the issue. It won't let me create a roll-up formula for those 2 fields and then create the percentage. Pretty lost at this point mate.

Comment: I think it is possible through the trigger only

Answer (score 4):

As you called out in your comment, this would not be an issue if you could use the Standard Rollup Summary fields to count the total leads and converted leads.  You cannot use the standard rollup summary to count leads on accounts though.

To get around this you have a few options.  You could look on the app exchange for an app that does this for you.  The advantage here is it doesn't require any custom coding on your part.  I would recommend the Rollup Helper if you want to go this route.  (I have no personal affiliation or interest in this product, just one that I have used int eh past and works well)

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI

If you want to go the route of coding, there are a few nifty packages out there that I would look into

Anthony Victorio wrote a nice utility for creating your own rollups.  Take a look [here](http://www.anthonyvictorio.com/salesforce/roll-up-summary-utility/)

Andy Fawcett also wrote a utility for this as well that you can find [here](http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/04/09/new-declarative-rollup-tool-release-community-powered/)

Once you choose any of these methods you can roll up your total leads and your converted leads.  then you just need to create a formula field that divides them.

Comment: Thanks sfdc_ninja! I'll check out the resources you gave me.

Comment: No worries.  Glad to help